# How to send XML soap request using php curl

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap

I am sending request through soap using php curl getting java Exception.
When I request for response I am getting error. I tried a lot at my end but problem is not solve.

```
$soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>";
  $soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n";
  $soap_request .= "  <soap:Body>\n"; 
  $soap_request .= "    <RevodocLead xmlns='http://localhost/'>\n";
  $soap_request .= "        <inode>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <version>1.0</version>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <sourceuserid>test@test.in</sourceuserid>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <sourceid>18641254455</sourceid>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <dealercode>1458445284</dealercode>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <created>18-12-2015 13:45EST</created>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <browser>Android Browser</browser>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <os>Macintosh</os>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <agent>atinek@gmail.com</agent>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <product>mortgage-renewal</product>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <name>success</name>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <address>success</address>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <email>success</email>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <phone>success</phone>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <propertyvalue>325000</propertyvalue>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <mortgage>300000</mortgage>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <referralcode>F3S2A2</referralcode>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <note>value</note>\n";
  $soap_request .= "            <futurecontact>yes</futurecontact>\n";
  $soap_request .= "        </inode>\n"; 
  $soap_request .= "    </RevodocLead>\n";
  $soap_request .= "  </soap:Body>\n";
  $soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";

$header = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: myactionMethod",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);


  if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
  } else {
    $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    //print 'Operation completed without any errors';
  }
```

I am getting error

> soap:Serverjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be
>   cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Comment: i reckon you will have to add your `$header` and `$soap_request` to your question, since the error states quite clearly that there is some unexpected string where an xml element was expected

Comment: Hi hexerel  i added both $header and $soap_request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code. It's working great.

```
class RevodocLeadSoapClient extends SoapClient {

    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
        $this->server = new SoapServer($wsdl, $options);
    }
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) { 
        $result = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version); 
        return $result; 
    } 
    function __anotherRequest($call, $params) {
        $location = 'https://www.t1.revodoc.com/ws/services/RevoLeadWebService';
        $action = 'http://localhost/'.$call;
        $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
                    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:typens="https://secure.maventa.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
                    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <RevodocLead xmlns="http://localhost/">';
        $request .= $params;
        $request .= '</RevodocLead>
                    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
        $result =$this->__doRequest($request, $location, $action, '1');
        return $result;
    } 
}

// Create new SOAP client
$wsdl = 'https://www.t1.revodoc.com/ws/services/RevoLeadWebService?wsdl';
$client = new RevodocLeadSoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'cache_ttl'     => 86400, 
    'trace'         => true,
    'exceptions'    => true,
));

$operations = "RevodocLead";

$soap_request .= "<inode>";
$soap_request .= "<version>1.0</version>";
$soap_request .= "<sourceuserid>test@test.in</sourceuserid>";
$soap_request .= "<sourceid>18641254455</sourceid>";
$soap_request .= "<dealercode>1458445284</dealercode>";
$soap_request .= "<created>18-12-2015 13:45EST</created>";
$soap_request .= "<browser>Android Browser</browser>";
$soap_request .= "<os>Macintosh</os>";
$soap_request .= "<agent>atinek@gmail.com</agent>";
$soap_request .= "<product>mortgage-renewal</product>";
$soap_request .= "<name>success</name>";
$soap_request .= "<address>success</address>";
$soap_request .= "<email>success</email>";
$soap_request .= "<phone>success</phone>";
$soap_request .= "<propertyvalue>325000</propertyvalue>";
$soap_request .= "<mortgage>300000</mortgage>";
$soap_request .= "<referralcode>F3S2A2</referralcode>";
$soap_request .= "<note>value</note>";
$soap_request .= "<futurecontact>yes</futurecontact>";
$soap_request .= "</inode>";

// Make the request
try {
    $request = $client->__anotherRequest($operations, $soap_request);
} catch (SoapFault $e ){
    echo "Last request:<pre>" . htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) . "</pre>";
    exit();
}
//Print Response. #RevodocLeadResponse
echo '<pre><b>', htmlentities($request), '</b></pre>';
```

Comment: Hi jayson in my case authenticatoin does not required

Comment: you can directly call the `__soapCall` method without `SoapHeader` and `__setSoapHeaders`

Comment: "SOAPAction: myactionMethod", defined at you header array.

Comment: $wsdl = 'mysite?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl); 


$soap_request['inode'] =  array('version' => '1.0',
'sourceuserid' => 'test@test.in',
'sourceid' => '15640435843584',
'dealercode' => '41358-21'
,'created' => '18-04-2015 13:45EST'
,'browser' => 'chrome
,'os' => 'linux'

);
$result = $client->__soapCall("RevodocLead", $soap_request);

print_r($result);
?>

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] java.lang.NullPointerException in /var/www/html/webservice/04.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/webservice/04.php(16): SoapClient->__soapCall('RevodocLead', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/webservice/04.php on line 16

Comment: its strange. you have to check `RevodocLead` method parameters at your WSDL file. i can help you if you provide more details.

Comment: let me know updated answer is working for you or not.

Comment: I already resolved my problem by removing \n from $soap_request .
Thanks for you support @jayson :-)

Comment: if my answer is right then mark it as correct. glad to help.