# SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Index: 1, Size: 1 error in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to get data from an API service using SOAP.Everything works fine except the data.
Here is the code

```
$body=array(
             'Origin' => 'BOM',
            'Destination' => 'DEL',
            'DepartDate' => '2013-09-05',
            'ReturnDate' => '2013-09-06',
            'AdultPax' => '1',
            'ChildPax' => '0',
            'InfantPax' => '0',
            'Currency' => 'INR',
            'Clientid' => 'XXX',
            'Clientpassword' => '*4X',
            'Clienttype' => 'XXXX',
            'Preferredclass' => 'E',
            'mode' => 'ONE',
            'PreferredAirline' => 'AI,G8,IC,6E,9W,S2,IT,9H,I7,SG');
```

Php code for executing SOAP

```
 $location_URL='http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient('http://59.162.33.102/ArzooWS/services/DOMFlightAvailability?wsdl');
try
{   
    print_r($client->__getFunctions());
   $result = $client->__call('getAvailability',$body);
   print_r($result);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

Result of `print_r($client->__getFunctions())` returns  `getAvailability`,when try to get the data i will get the exception

`SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Index: 1, Size: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\apihack\index.php:80 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\apihack\index.php(80): SoapClient->__call('getAvailability', Array) #1 {main}`

Comment: Refer this link it would be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694916/how-to-send-xml-soap-request-using-php-curl/

Comment: Cant understand it.could you please simplify this?